# jquery iterate through cell column in table

Tags: jquery

I have the following html table (I can provide the html if required).
Each name within a cell, is a anchor tag in a li. For example, If 'curly' is clicked, I'd like to loop through each cell in that column and see that other classes curly as applied. (My aim is to apply validation, so a block of no more than 3 names can be red in a column).

As anyone got an idea how this can be achieved?

```
 HTML: <div class="container">
    <table id="tbl_calendar" class="table table-bordered calendar">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></td>
                <td id="2015-11-30" style="font-weight: bold;">Monday <br> 30/11/2015 </td>
                <td id="2015-12-01" style="font-weight: bold;">Tuesday <br> 01/12/2015</td>
                <td id="2015-12-02" style="font-weight: bold;">Wednesday <br> 02/12/2015</td>
                <td id="2015-12-03" style="font-weight: bold;">Thursday <br> 03/12/2015</td>
                <td id="2015-12-04" style="font-weight: bold;">Friday <br> 04/12/2015</td>
            </tr>

            <tr><td id='910' style='font-weight: bold'> 9-10 </td><td style='padding: 0;' bgcolor='#FAFAFA'>
                            <ul class='doctorList'>
                                <li><a id='1' href='#'>Curly</a></li>
                                <li><a id='2' href='#'>Larry</a></li>
                                <li><a id='3' href='#'>Moe</a></li>
                            </ul>
                           </td><td style='padding: 0;' bgcolor='#FAFAFA'>
                            <ul class='doctorList'>
                                <li><a id='1' href='#'>Curly</a></li>
                                <li><a id='2' href='#'>Larry</a></li>
                                <li><a id='3' href='#'>Moe</a></li>
                            </ul>
                           </td><td style='padding: 0;' bgcolor='#FAFAFA'>
                            <ul class='doctorList'>
                                <li><a id='1' href='#'>Curly</a></li>
                                <li><a id='2' href='#'>Larry</a></li>
                                <li><a id='3' href='#'>Moe</a></li>
                            </ul>
                           </td><td style='padding: 0;' bgcolor='#FAFAFA'>
                            <ul class='doctorList'>
                                <li><a id='1' href='#'>Curly</a></li>
                                <li><a id='2' href='#'>Larry</a></li>
                                <li><a id='3' href='#'>Moe</a></li>
                            </ul>
                           </td><td style='padding: 0;' bgcolor='#FAFAFA'>
                            <ul class='doctorList'>
                                <li><a id='1' href='#'>Curly</a></li>
                                <li><a id='2' href='#'>Larry</a></li>
                                <li><a id='3' href='#'>Moe</a></li>
                            </ul>
                           </td></tr><tr><td id='1011' style='font-weight: bold'> 10-11 </td><td style='padding: 0;' bgcolor='#FAFAFA'>
                            <ul class='doctorList'>
                                <li><a id='1' href='#'>Curly</a></li>
                                <li><a id='2' href='#'>Larry</a></li>
                                <li><a id='3' href='#'>Moe</a></li>
                            </ul>
                           </td><td style='padding: 0;' bgcolor='#FAFAFA'>
                            <ul class='doctorList'>
                                <li><a id='1' href='#'>Curly</a></li>
                                <li><a id='2' href='#'>Larry</a></li>
                                <li><a id='3' href='#'>Moe</a></li>
                            </ul>
                           </td><td style='padding: 0;' bgcolor='#FAFAFA'>
                            <ul class='doctorList'>
                                <li><a id='1' href='#'>Curly</a></li>
                                <li><a id='2' href='#'>Larry</a></li>
                                <li><a id='3' href='#'>Moe</a></li>
                            </ul>
                           </td><td style='padding: 0;' bgcolor='#FAFAFA'>
                            <ul class='doctorList'>
                                <li><a id='1' href='#'>Curly</a></li>
                                <li><a id='2' href='#'>Larry</a></li>
                                <li><a id='3' href='#'>Moe</a></li>
                            </ul>
                           </td><td style='padding: 0;' bgcolor='#FAFAFA'>
                            <ul class='doctorList'>
                                <li><a id='1' href='#'>Curly</a></li>
                                <li><a id='2' href='#'>Larry</a></li>
                                <li><a id='3' href='#'>Moe</a></li>
                            </ul>
```

This shows what a 'booked' appointments looks like.
[image]

Comment: Please do add the html

Comment: "My aim is to apply validation, so a block of no more than 3 names can be red in a column" can you elaborate a bit more on this requirement?

Comment: You have duplicate IDs in your anchors. That's not valid, IDs must be unique.

Comment: Yes, so for each red name I apply a class called booked. No person can have more than 3 appointments booked in a block. for example, if a person as an appointment for 9-10, 10-11 & 11-12 I will need to return false if 12-13 is clicked. @DelightedD0D

Comment: You seem to be missing `</thead>`, so all the rows are in the table heading. Is that intentional or a copying error?

Comment: @Barmar this is only part of the table (first 2 rows). each tag is given a unqiue id via javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.index()` to get the column number of the `td` containing the clicked link. Then substitute that into a selector to find the same column in all the rows.

```
$("td a").click(function() {
    var col = $(this).closest("td").index()+1; // +1 because :nth-child is 1-based
    $(this).closest("table").find("td:nth-child("+col+") a.booked").each(function() {
        // do something with the booked anchors
    });
});
```

If you just want to count the number of booked items, you don't need a loop, you can just use `.length`.

```
$("td a").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("booked");
    var col = $(this).closest("td").index()+1; // +1 because :nth-child is 1-based
    var booked = $(this).closest("table").find("td:nth-child("+col+") a.booked");
    if (booked.length > 3) {
        alert("Too many items booked for " + $(this).closest("table").find("tr:first td:nth-child("+col+")").text());
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, so there I have the column. How can I loop through the anchors to check if 3 columns contain 'booked' class in a row? @barmar

Comment: That's what `.each` does.

Comment: great, but my problem, is to see if there are 3 booked in a block. For example, if 9-10, 10,11, & 11,12 are all booked then alert message.

Comment: So check if the row indexes of all the selected elements contain 3 consecutive values. That's a completely separate problem from the one you asked about.

Comment: That's what goes into `//do something with the booked anchors`.

Comment: I know how to get the row number, I'm jut unsure and how I check that 3 in a row are booked for the same users. E.g. Curly has 3 in a row.

Comment: Get all the row numbers into an array, check whether there are 3 consecutive numbers in the array. I'll bet you can find something that does this by searching SO.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution to my question, thank to the pointers from @barmer, I have been able to understand jQuery a little better. Please feel free to improve my answer (especially the super long if statement).

```
        var clickedDoctorId = clickedApp.attr("id").slice(-1);
        var col = $(clickedApp).closest("td").index()+1; //gets the column index of the clicked appointment.
        var booked = $(clickedApp).closest("table").find("td:nth-child("+col+") a.booked"); //gets any booked appointments in the clicked column
        var bookedAppArray = [];

        booked.each(function() {
            //compares the doctor Id of each booked appointment in the selected column, with the clicked doctorId
          if(($(this).attr("id")).slice(-1) == clickedDoctorId){

              //appointment row index of appointment booked for the same doctor as the click:
              var appRowIndex = $(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex;
              //add booked appointment index to the array:
              bookedAppArray.push(appRowIndex);
          }
        });

        var clickedAppRowIndex = $(clickedApp).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex;
        //alert(clickedAppRowIndex);

        //check if array contains 3 value before, or 3 values after the clicked appointment:
        if((clickedAppRowIndex - 1 in bookedAppArray && clickedAppRowIndex - 2 in bookedAppArray && clickedAppRowIndex - 3 in bookedAppArray) || (clickedAppRowIndex + 1 in bookedAppArray && clickedAppRowIndex + 2 in bookedAppArray && clickedAppRowIndex + 3 in bookedAppArray))  {
            return true;
        }
```